# Не работает функция strtok. Вероятно. другие параметры

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char * pch;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
```

не работает в ms visual studio c++;
Пишет ошибка: использовать *strtok_s*
Прописываю с новой функцией - виндовс начинает искать ошибку.
В общем задача: разбить стоку на слова (разделители пробел и ,.-).
Как сделать, чтобы функция заработала?

Comment: Как у вас это скомпилировалось?

    *char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";

Comment: А ещё, если `str` — это константная строка `"- This, a sample string."`, её **нельзя** скармливать `strtok`, т. к. `strtok` изменяет переданные ей данные (как сегодня уже отмечал @avp).

Answer (score 1):

Интересно поработать некромантом :)

Вероятно, VC++ сообщил что-то вроде

> warning C4996: 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

а в настройках указано "трактовать все предупреждения как ошибки".

Один вариант решения указан прямо в сообщении: начать код со строки

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Второй — и в самом деле использовать `strtok_s`, только не просто заменяя имя, а используя так, как того хочет VC++, с переменной контекста:

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char * pch, *context;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok_s(str," ,.-",&context);
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok_s (NULL," ,.-",&context);
}
```